# .wsf file creation always throwing File Access Denied Permission error

Tags: sql-server, windows

In Windows 7 I am trying to install SQL Server 2014 and the installation is failing every time while creating the file `wscript.wsf` with a permission error. I have full admin rights still not able to complete this installation.

When I try to create a blank file with the extension `.wsf`, Windows is throwing a "Permission denied" error also, and saying you need to get the Admin rights. I am using Administrator user.

Please help me to complete this installation

Regards,
Manohar